# Update cell value to NOW() only when a specific cell is updated Without Apps Scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The idea is pretty simple, have a cell log **date and time** like `NOW()` when a cell in the same row or a specific cell is changed, But i didn't find a solution without using Apps Scripts.

**Example:**
[image]

Ideally I'd like to use one formula to cover the whole Column, This is the best I came up with, it dones't work as intended so I didn't "beautify" it
`IF(ISBLANK(AJ2),{"",""},IF(AI2="",{"",AI1},IF(AI2>NOW(),{"",AI1},)))` In `AH2`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something alike this:

```
=arrayformula(IF(A2:A,IF(B2:B="",NOW(),B2:B),""))
```

- `Enable iterative calculation` in sheets setting as in screenshot
- Format the `Column B` to timestamp format

[image]

[image]